# Select a Single Column from an Object Observable collection

Tags: c#, wpf, selection, observablecollection

I am having an `ObservableCollection` having 4 columns populated at run time.

```
public ObservableCollection<object> SelectedRows;
```

I want to get an Id Column values from this collection but I am unable to get this using LINQ because at compile time i do not know that Id column is present in the collection.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
vat w = from s in db.table
        select s.id;

foreach (var i in w)
{ 
    console.writeln(i);
}
```

Comment: It will not work because s.id is not available. This Id is not given at the time of declaration and coming at run time.

Comment: This worked for me:                                                                  var selectedIndexId = from itemSelectedRows in LstIndexId.ToList<object>()
                                      select itemSelectedRows.GetType().GetProperty("Id").GetValue(itemSelectedRows, null);

Answer (score 0):

```
var selectedIndexId = from itemSelectedRows in <YourListName>.ToList<object>()
                      select itemSelectedRows.GetType().GetProperty("Id").GetValue(itemSelectedRows, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using data binding:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedRows}"
         DisplayMemberPath="The property to be displayed"
         SelectValuePath="The property that SelectedValue would bind to"
         SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedRowId}" />
```

If you need to do this in C#, I highly recommend your objects implement a common interface you could cast to. Otherwise, you can use the `dynamic` keyword:

```
SelectedRows.Cast<dynamic>().Select(d => (int)d.Id)
```